# Alien invasion happened and humanity made powered armor suits to fight

Tags: story-identification, anime

I don't exactly know the name of this anime/cartoon so here I am describing it.

It was aired in 2002 on TV. The story contained mainly an alien invasion and a force of power armor guys who fight the alien. The main guy rode on a surf board type of thing while he was launched from a truck which has catapults to launch people. The fight ended then with the force divided in 2 groups who fight for ultimate power. There was something called Giam which was in 2 pieces and the one who combined it get a lot of much power in his suit.

The suit the main guy is using is blue and white, and the gun he use while fighting is some sort of laser beam type. I also remember one word from end credits and it was like 'm-divers' or 'm-drivers' or something like that.

I assume the series has more than 2 or 3 seasons and also the total span is nearly 70 to 80 episodes. I watched in Hindi(India), but I think it was a US or Japanese origin story.

If anyone knows about the show please give the name; I have been searching for it for the last 6 months.

Comment: 1) What country/language/channel did you see this in/on, if you know? 2) So you mean the alien invasion was stopped but the groups of human fighters split into two groups? 3) Do you remember anything about the art style, colors, etc, or what the aliens looked like?

Comment: 1)well i watched in Hindi(India) but as much as i can say it was US or Japanese origin story.
2)yes,and also there is something called Giam which is in 2 piece and the one who combine it get so much power in his suit.
3)i don't know much about style but the suit main guy is using is blue and white. and the gun he use while fighting is some sort of laser beam type.

Comment: and i am also not sure about language and the TV channel.

Comment: and i also remember one word from end credits and it was like 'm-divers' or 'm-drivers' something like that.

Comment: Any chance it was AM Driver? Aka Get Ride AMDriver. https://cdn.myanimelist.net/images/anime/12/21726.jpg

Comment: yup it match,and no wonder i am not able to find it as i can see i am not able to find any episode of it online as right now i am searching.
if u know a place where i can watch it online,as i am looking for it but i am not able to find it right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm wondering if this is [Get Ride AMDriver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AM_Driver).

[image: A DVD cover of Get Ride AM Driver, with a blue and white powered armor figure surfing in the foreground and a man's head and torso in the background.]

It's a little late (2004), but it [aired in India](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_anime_distributed_in_India), and sounds like "m-driver". The main character's suit is blue and white.

> In the future, human beings are attacked by beings called the
> Bug-chine, which appeared a few years back. No normal human weapon can
> defeat the Bug-chine, but there is hope. It is the AMDrivers that will
> save the earth. They are solders using the latest "AM Technology".
> With overwhelming power, they will beat the Bug-chine one after
> another and become heroes, as well as capture the hearts of their
> fans.

[Possibly](http://landofobscusion.blogspot.com/2016/07/demo-disc-vol-6-illumitoons-illusive.html) re the combining into something more powerful, or else the idea of catapulting off of a truck:

> Episode 5 introduces the Binary Silhouette Armor, "Bisar" for short,
> which is a series of vehicles (motorbike, giant floating board,
> glider, etc.) that the AM Drivers can use & even combine with to
> create new forms

[Re](http://www.macrossworld.com/mwf/topic/46078-get-ride-amdriver/) the team splitting up:

> The star of the idol-like TV show is revealed to be the bad guy, and a
> very competent one to boot who almost manages to win. The original
> "bad guys" end up helping the heroes in defeating him.

Surfing:

[image: A low resolution anime screenshot of several figures in power armor surfing through the air.]

Answer (score 0):

Could you be thinking of [Eureka Seven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eureka_Seven). I haven't seen it, but I am aware of it because of Mechasuits riding surfboards.

[image: Mecha on Surfboard]

Comment: no, its not because i check that long before.anyway thanks.